# Manually synchronize hashmap without using concurrent and synchronize hashmap

Tags: multithreading

I have a hashmap. In which multiple threads will add entires to it. A new thread is created to see all current values in hashmap. If i try this , hashmap throws concurrent Modification exception. It can be overcomed by using concurrentHashMap and SynchronizedHashMap . but i need only my simple hashmap to be get synchronized .

[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu1zh.jpg)

when i am working with it. It throws me concurrent modification exception.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Please take some time and post a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).